# Unable to configure FontAwesome for WASM

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

I have followed the references on the web https://platform.uno/docs/articles/features/custom-fonts.html and also https://platform.uno/docs/articles/features/custom-fonts.html and cannot get it to work.

I used powershell to create the base64 then added it to my Fonts.css at the **...** location.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesomeRegular";
    src: url(data:application/x-font-otf;charset=utf-8;base64,...) format('otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I then added the following in app.xaml in the ResourceDictionary

```
<FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeRegularWasm">ms-apps:///Assets/FontAwesomeRegular#Font Awesome 5 Free</FontFamily>
```

where FontAwesomeRegular is the font-family name given in @font-face above and **Font Awesome 5 Free** is the FontAwesome font family name.

My test Xaml looks like:

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Content>
        <FontIcon FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeRegularWasm}" Glyph="&#xf7a5;" />
    </ToggleButton.Content>
</ToggleButton>
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an usage example:

```xml
<Page ...>
    
    <Page.Resources>
        <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeRegularWasm2">ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/FontAwesomeRegular.ttf#FontAwesomeRegular</FontFamily>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton.Content>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeRegularWasm}" Glyph="&#xf164;" />
                </ToggleButton.Content>
            </ToggleButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

With the font defined as follows in the `Fonts.css` file, as you've found:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesomeRegular";
    /* fa-regular-400.woff2 */
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,___CHANGEME___)format('woff');
}
```

One of the way to generate the base64 string is to use some online base64 conversion tool, or use WSL/linux with the following:

```sh
base64 -w 0 fa-regular-400.woff2 > fa-regular-400.txt
```

Then replace the css `___CHANGEME___` with the contents of the `fa-regular-400.txt` file.

Note that the important part of the file definition is the portion after the font name:

```xml
<FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeRegularWasm2">ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/FontAwesomeRegular.ttf#FontAwesomeRegular</FontFamily>
```

Where `FontAwesomeRegular` must match the `font-family: "FontAwesomeRegular";` name defined in the css.